# error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component Although my login page's route is located inside <BrowserRouter>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am practicing code to manage user information such as login using React, Nodejs, and Redux.

After react router v6, I understand that we use react-dom's "useNavigate()" instead of pushing to get to the desired path.I'm also practicing this method, but there's an error like the title.

Login Route was placed inside  in App.js and "useNavigate()" was called inside Login function in LoginPage.js.

However, the error has not improved at all. How can I use navigate function in my code?

I am attaching my app.js and LoginPage.js.

app.js

```
import './App.css';
import {
    Route,
    Routes,
    BrowserRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

import LandingPage from "./components/views/LandingPage/LandingPage";
import LoginPage from "./components/views/LoginPage/LoginPage";
import NavBar from "./components/views/NavBar/NavBar";
import RegisterBar from "./components/views/RegisterBar/RegisterBar";
import Footer from "./components/views/Footer/Footer";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/landing" element={LandingPage()} />
          <Route path="/login" element={LoginPage()} />  
          <Route path="/nav" element={NavBar()} />
          <Route path="/register" element={RegisterBar()} />
          <Route path="/footer" element={Footer()} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

LoginPage.js

```
import React, { useState }from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { loginUser } from "../../../_action/user_action";

function LoginPage(){
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [Password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const onEmailHandler = (event) => {
        setEmail(event.currentTarget.value)
    }
    const onPasswordHandler = (event) => {
        setPassword(event.currentTarget.value)
    }
    const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let body = {
            email: Email,
            password: Password
        }

        dispatch(loginUser(body)).then(response => {
            if(response.payload.loginSuccess){
                navigate("/");
            } else {
                alert('error')
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <div style={{
            display:"flex", justifyContent:"center", alignItems: "center",
            width: '100%', height: '100vh'
        }}>
            <form style={{display:"flex", flexDirection: 'column'}} onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type={"email"} value={Email} onChange={onEmailHandler}/>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type={"password"} value={Password} onChange={onPasswordHandler}/>
                <button type={"submit"}>Log in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default LoginPage
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to write:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

and replace `BrowserRouter` with `Router`.

Code Changes will look like this -

```js
import './App.css';
import {
    Route,
    Routes,
    BrowserRouter as Router
} from "react-router-dom";

import LandingPage from "./components/views/LandingPage/LandingPage";
import LoginPage from "./components/views/LoginPage/LoginPage";
import NavBar from "./components/views/NavBar/NavBar";
import RegisterBar from "./components/views/RegisterBar/RegisterBar";
import Footer from "./components/views/Footer/Footer";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/landing" element={LandingPage()} />
          <Route path="/login" element={LoginPage()} />  
          <Route path="/nav" element={NavBar()} />
          <Route path="/register" element={RegisterBar()} />
          <Route path="/footer" element={Footer()} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```